# Symbol not supported in jxBrowser?

Tags: jxbrowser

I have created a Symbol in jxBrowser.  Although it works in a javascript script inside jxBrowser (chromium), if the symbol is returned to java, it does not come as a JSValue, but as a Java::ComTeamdevJxbrowserChromium::am:0x7f4701b1.  Symbol is a new type in ES06 and I presume that it should be implemented as a JSValue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser JavaScript Java Bridge API doesn't support Symbol type. The list of supported JavaScript types you can find at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013062-calling-java-from-javascript

Comment: Are you planning to add this type in the near future?

Comment: For now, we don't have any plans to support this type, but you can send feature request via https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/tickets/new so we could add it to our backlog.